# Android security and RESTFUL server with Google Auth (Firebase)

Tags: android, security, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, restful-authentication

I have an Android App, for the login use google account using Firebase. When I launch the Android application, Firebase returns a token with user information. I sent that token to my server to validate. In the token there is a date and an expiration date (1 hour).

Client -> Android
Server -> RESTFUL PHP

From here I do not know what is safe or what is the safest way to communicate:

1st - In each https request from the client to the server send the Firebase token until it expires. (For each request I must collect the public keys provided by Google in a URL to decode the token)

2nd - When my server receives the Firebase token, it must return a new token (generated by the server) that the client must send in each https request to the server until it expires.

Which is the good way ? I am wrong and is there another better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct option is the 2nd.

Although you have to make a query to Google for each request to decode the token, the real reason is that the token generated by the server may contain other data related to the application: permissions, profile, or whatever interests us.

To generate the Token on the PHP jwt server

composer require firebase / php-jwt